# NoSQL schema for folder structure

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have documents that represent a folder structure. A folder can contain other folders (nested), theoretically unlimited levels deep but more realistically 3 or 4 levels for our application. I need to be able to retrieve a single item (a node) and perhaps embedding will make this task a bit difficult?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Should have looked at the docs! http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Trees+in+MongoDB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Trees+in+MongoDB) give a great summary of the more popular/common ways to store hierarchical data in mongodb.

[Embedding documents](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Trees+in+MongoDB#TreesinMongoDB-FullTreeinSingleDocument) - have significant drawbacks

> - Hard to search
> - Hard to get back partial results
> - Can get unwieldy if you need a huge tree. Further there is a limit on the size of documents in MongoDB – 16MB in v1.8 (limit may rise in future versions).

As you need to be able to retrieve single items - that is *not* likely to be the best option for your use case.

[Array of ancestors](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Trees+in+MongoDB#TreesinMongoDB-ArrayofAncestors) or [materialized path](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Trees+in+MongoDB#TreesinMongoDB-MaterializedPaths%28FullPathinEachNode%29) are likely to be much more suitable for what you've described - you could choose to use the full filepath for _id since that is unique and the path you would want to find data by more commonly.